# How to properly handle session and access token with Facebook PHP SDK 3.0?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, session

In the PHP 3.0 SDK there is no `getSession()` or any session handling from outside the Facebook api available. Some days ago the developers of facebook have also somehow updated the JavaScript sdk, according to **[this blog entry](http://knoopgroup.org/)** and **[this bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18633)**.

> Within the last few days, a change was
>   introduced into the hosted JS SDK
>   which broke all compatility between it
>   and the current PHP SDK (2.x and 3.x).
>   Developers who utilize both the JS and
>   PHP SDK on their websites are likely
>   to see server-side API failure.

However, I don't know if that really effects my problem. Like in **[this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460531/facebook-session-transfer-js-sdk-to-php-sdk)** I am retrieving the access token of the OAuth dialog with PHP and save the new access token in the session.

### Current workaround

The following code shows how I am handling this sessions. `$_REQUEST['session']` is the content of the response of the OAuth dialog.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['session'])) {

    $response = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['session']), true);

    if(isset($response['access_token'])) {
        $this->api->setAccessToken($response['access_token']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->api->getAccessToken();
    }

}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && ! isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) 
    $this->api->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
    Session::invalidate('fbuser');
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = '';
}
```

Here is how I handle the user data:

```
try {
    $this->user = Session::getVar('fbuser');
    if ($this->user === false || is_null($this->user)) {
        $facebookUser = $this->api->api('me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name');
        $this->user = new FBUserModel(array('fbId' => $facebookUser['fbId'], ...));
        Session::setVar('fbuser', $this->user);
    }
}
```

### The Problem

Everything looks fine while testing. Only once an error occured: **the first time** after permission was set. Now, since the app is online, it seems as if the error occurs on average with every second user in

```
$facebookUser = $this->api->api('me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name');
```

with the error:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

### Question

So why is this happening? It is very hard to debug since the error seems to only occur when a user enters the app the first time, after the app authentication and the access token has changed. And even that is not happening every time. How should I handle the session and access token right with the new PHP SDK?

Any help would be highly appreciatied!

### Edit

I found out that there are some IE issues with cookies/session inside an iFrame. As seen **[in this blog post](http://adamyoung.net/IE-Blocking-iFrame-Cookies)**. With that hint and some further research I added the following lines in my bootstrap:

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Now its much better, but the information from about 2 of 50 users get lost between the steps landing page (authentication) -> formular -> and registration. So there is still something I missed.

### Edit 2

I edited my user handling from

```
if ($this->user === false || is_null($this->user)) {
    // get user data
}
```

to

```
if ((is_object($this->user) && $this->user->fbId == '') || $this->user === false || is_null($this->user)) {
    // get user data
}
```

This seems to help a little bit. I think the main problem is somewhere in my session.

Furthermore I added a try/catch block to see if somewhere in my app a Facebook `OAuthException` is thrown. If this is the case, I redirect the **top location** to the Facebook Page and Tab to get a **new signed request**. Though this might help solve this problem, I want to prevent my app from having to redirect the user.

### Edit 3

After some days of intense debugging and logging I found out, that the `$_REQUEST['session']` coming from the **FB.ui permissions.request method** is empty infrequently.

Here is how I handle it:

This is the stuff I always included:

```
FB.provide("UIServer.Methods", {'permissions.request': {size : {width: 575, height: 300}, url: 'connect/uiserver.php', transform : FB.UIServer.genericTransform}});
```

And this function is called on form submit. Always worked for me, but somehow it still sends the form although `session == ''`.

```
function getPermission(form) {

    session = $('#' + $(form).attr('id') + ' input[name="session"]');

    if($(session).val() != '') {
        form.submit();
        return;
    }

    FB.ui({method: "permissions.request", "perms": 'user_photos'}, function callback(info){
        if(info.status=='connected' && info.session !== null) {
            $(session).val(JSON.stringify(info.session));
            form.submit();
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: could you give more information on what your "bootstrap" is and what else it contains?

Comment: @danjp my bootstrap contains path configurations, auto loader, config, and session handling. The only thing relevant to my problem is what I already posted: the `use_trans_sid` and the P3P header.

Comment: +1 for mentioning p3p headers. Those things killed me for weeks when trying to create a Facebook app in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### My solution

Well, since everything I did was just a workaround until the new JS SDK comes out, there seems to be no best practice. Setting `session.use_trans_sid` to 1 and adding the P3P header helped to overcome IE iFrame cookie issues (see my first edit). After a few days of heavy debugging I found out, that FB.ui's `permission_request` does not send a new access token everytime (<5%).

If this happens, something went wrong. But this little something is driving me crazy. Since this happens infrequently, I can bear redirecting users back to the facebook tab to get a new signed request. With the new JS SDK, hopefully, this won't happen anymore.

### Update: final solution

There was one little thing I have overseen and the solution can be found here: [FB is not defined problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331165/fb-is-not-defined-problem/5331861#5331861)
I did not **load the JS SDK asynchronously**! This explains everything. Sometimes the all.js file was not loaded fast enough, so there was a JS error. Due to that, neither the permission dialog nor the JS validation worked and an empty #session input value was sent.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Hopefully, the PHP-SDK will get updated soon so that you'll have your system properly integrated.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using now **PHP SDK 3.x** without any problem.

Naitik the class author removed the **getSession()** function, and now if you want to know if the user is authenticated or not, use **getUser()**.

For Access token, it's very simple, use this function **getAccessToken()**, and you'll get the access token to make **Graph or Rest API** calls.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
//USER Logged-In
}
else {
//USER not Logged-In
}

//TO GET ACCESS TOKEN
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();


//MAKE AN API CALL WITH IT
$user_info = $facebook->api('me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name&access_token='.$access_token);
```

Comment: you didn't understand my problem: I have to get the permission through JavaScript. The PHP 3.x SKD does not communicate well with the currently available JS SDK. The access token is NOT changed automatically. So, I wrote this workaround to save the new access token in the session. And THIS is only working about 95% of the time...not 100%

Comment: @Sascha Galley - do you really need to get permission only using JS ? using PHP SDK for getting permission should save you from this problem.

Comment: @Sergey Nester: I know, but it is a requirement for this and other projects to use the JS dialog. If there was no possibility at all to combine the old JS with the new PHP SDK I could argue with that. But as already mentioned my workaround is working in >95%. There is only one little thing that keeps me from 100%. I could also catch the error, reload the whole page and get the new signed request, but I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I would debug a little more. Log the contents of the requests. What’s stored in $_SESSION, what’s passed in $_REQUEST. Also, check if it’s a browser issue (is it happening regardless of the browser, or is there a pattern?)

But since fixing the cookie issue in IE (P3P header) helped, my guess is that there are some browsers left, that deny third party cookies. As far as I know, some versions of Safari and Opera does that by default. 
In addition, this error states that there was no `access_token` provided, as opposed to invalid or expired one.

You can test that by disabling third party cookies ([using about:config in firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.cookieBehavior) for instance), deauthorizing your app (using the "Apps and websites" section on the bottom of [Facebook Privacy settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy)), deleting cookies (related to your canvas URL) and then launching the application.

BTW, there’s always a possibility of facebook not returning access token even when it should, as [described in bug 17236](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17236)

Comment: thanks, this is the best answer so far. i will not accept it immediately to let it be open for further research, but I give you the deserved bounty right now. so...stay tuned :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i've run in the same trouble seems i've solved it with watching the JS API and redirect to the PHP-SDK Login Page if User Information is readable

example:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function check_fb_status(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response){
     if(response.name) window.location='<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl(); ?>';
     else check_fb_status();
    });
}

check_fb_status();

</script>
```

if the script succed it loads the loginpage, and user got recognized by both JS and PHP SDK ;)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Facebook posted an update to the PHP SDK about 2 hours ago which adds support for the new cookie format, if you're creating a session on the client using the JavaScript SDK. The update can be found at the [Facebook PHP-SDK GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).