# cannot to connect to facebook with PHP SDK3.2.3

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, userid

According to countless examples and variations of this on the internet, this should work. I have read many similar cases and comments but have not found a clear answer. This does print an access token but fails to authenticate. `echo $user` always returns 0. I am suspicious there is some configuration issue on http://developers.facebook.com where you get the appID, something in those settings I haven't got quite right. Thanks for any help.

```
<?  
require 'src/facebook.php';  

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(  

 'appId'  => '{appID}',  
 'secret' => '{secret}',  
 'cookie' =>  'true',
 'baseurl' => 'http://{baseUrl}'  

  ));  

  $user = $facebook->getUser() ;  
  echo $user;  
  print $facebook->getAccessToken();  
?>
```

Comment: `baseurl` should not be  `http://mizu.net46.net/src/facebook.php` change it to  `http://mizu.net46.net/CallbackFile.php` which is either  `facebookpost.php`, 
`facebookpost1.php`,
`facebookpost2.php`,
`facebookpost3.php`,
`facebookpost4.php` or
`facebookpost5.php`, remember to change it to that in your App dashboard, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled with the settings on the developers.facebook.com long enough I finally found a combination that worked.at this time I can connect and post to my facebook account when I run the app on localhost, why it doesnt work on the webserver is another question.

Answer (score 0):

a snippet of your code,

```
'baseurl' => 'http://mizu.net46.net/src/facebook.php'
```

`baseurl` **must not** be `facebook.php` it should be

```
'baseurl' => 'http://example.com/myApp/CallbackFile.php'
```

remember to match `baseurl` with your website/site URL in your app dashboard

[image: sample of site url setting]

duplicates (further reading):

- [facebook->getUser returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484478/facebook-getuser-returns-0)
- [Facebook authentication in function - getUser() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367072/facebook-authentication-in-function-getuser-returns-0)
- [$facebook->getUser() always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417516/facebook-getuser-always-returns-0)
- [facebook->getUser() returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367924/facebook-getuser-returning-0)

Comment: Adam, thanks, I made some progress fiddling with the formatting, but am still having problems. I must have got the formatting syntax correct now in terms of the AppId and secret because then I see facebook dialogue box pops up asking me to give the app permission. after I check ok, it goes into redirect loop. I run the script again, and there is redirect loop everytime so the handshake or the authentication is not being finished. I can duplicate this same sequence when I create  a new app, so my theory is there something that has to be done to fix the redirect loop.

Comment: "mizu3 will receive the following info: your public profile and friend list. " click cancel or okay. if I  click cancel and run the script again I will get the same question again and again, as long as I cancel. once I click OK , and authorize the App then I have redirect loop everytime I run the script from then on.

Comment: check your error_log, are you running your script on `localhost`? if yes, that's the reason because Facebook PHP SDK can't be tested an ran on L/M/WAMP

Comment: I am running the script on a web hosting server. (not localhost)

Comment: maybe you have some code that I could add to my script that might resolve the problem?  the only thing thats shows up in the log is when I deliberately change that the key that gets logged. other then that nothing.

Comment: Your app is in sandbox, turn it off so I can debug it :)?

Comment: there isnt any sandbox feature anymore. I am not familiar with what that translates into their current model. anyway I got it working on localhost. why it the same script gives me an error when I try to run it on the webserver I havent figured out yet.........