# Why is my test application in an endless redirect loop?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the PHP SDK Version 3.1.1 in order to make a simple call to the Graph API. I am running it locally at http://local.fb-sandbox. The facebook application settings have the site URL set to http://local.fb-sandbox/.

I am redirected to the facebook login page and then to the page requesting my permission when I go to http://local.fb-sandbox but the application then goes into a redirect loop between a URL like:

```
http://local.fb-sandbox/?state=e9c091bb61afe08139af4e3b153a1e9e&code=AQBDJ4yMWVOIrukx6nRkxhNbnPH9nX6OvuqOWhVJEAgLkq6Lz27iq_-B6AIAGQ_cOpBIZktCPLLs_G5Hpt8QO5PRhDUN8l-Yu3JuT0YTzwVQiAqBlgutgia60lRT-ZzE3IHguStHq4gtuPQYJh423TBer-mB8BsqERvNsoF1L4NNe90WAWU8--MFAU3Oc4eeXyI#_=_
```

and

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=375741229103324&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.fb-sandbox%2F%3Fstate%3Dccd13778febb68d3eb1f4763a99b2ace%26code%3DAQBFegtkch4m34-2F9KMKgScrPhWzI0qeKJlvnM6uAD81BYm2xakv0S7DEbUrNwlECrgth5-YHdT8IR_vCBzW29QMh3ecOiiEk7P03wQG2V2gaxAUsMqOOZvTl_Oq3SefiLn9BvBAPQSGXQdRSZBVdsUqDT1aZ430Lcx8Ic6axaHSyHwlkkNK5EjRhYdkjYYz0YmENk64kRf4tvmX4WrH6f4&state=19a3862962dd0422628eb7c28a832380&scope=email%2Cread_stream%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_videos&fbconnect=1#_=_
```

I have a call to session_start() at the top of my script and have tried both with and without it. The PHP cookie is being set fine.

I've seen a lot of similar questions on here regarding this redirection loop but none of the suggested answers resolved it and they are all quite old. Should this work on localhost? AM I missing an application setting in the app settings on Facebook?

**UPDATE**

So it seems that if you use the code from here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ then it works. The php-sdk example on github completely ignores this and does not include the fact that you need to check whether 'code' is set and generate your own CSRF token. You then need to make a call to grab an access token before being able to make a call to the Graph API.

Also, the SDK's getLoginURL() method returns an https:// URL which doesn't seem to work. If I craft my own URL then it works.

***WORKING CODE:***

```
if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$login_url_params = array(
      'scope' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos',
      'fbconnect' =>  1,
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://local.fb-sandbox/',
'state'=>$_SESSION['state']
   ); //using this array via the sdk does not work

    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state']; //this url works

    //var_dump($dialog_url);echo "<br />";
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    //var_dump($login_url);
    header("Location:{$dialog_url}");//works
    //header("Location:{$login_url}");//does not work
    exit;
}



if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://xxxx0:80',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
      $response = file_get_contents($token_url, FALSE, $cxContext);

      $params = null;
      parse_str($response, $params);

      $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];

      $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, FALSE, $cxContext));
      //var_dump($user);exit;
}

//var_dump($user);exit;
  return $app->render('test.html',array('myvar', $user));
  exit();
```

Note that I am going through a proxy so have to set a context for the file_get_contents() calls.

If anyone can convert my code to use the proper SDK methods and get it working (bearing in mind that I need it to work behind a proxy) then you'll get the bounty.

Comment: Having same issue; only happens the first time a user auth's the app. Php giving me the same error as you.

Comment: what does **var_dump($user);** output?

Comment: @GilBirman : that outputs '0'

Comment: since you are wondering, have you tried checking the `$_REQUEST` variable if it contains the `state` parameter? it seems that `$_REQUEST['state']` is always null. Also how your full `htaccess` looks like?

Comment: The state and code are in $_REQUEST. I have added my .htaccess. I think I have ruled that out as the cause though

Comment: do you have a canvas url set up for the application? is it the same? Also (I don't know about this, but checking) are you sure that you can have facebook apps running at urls that can't be reached by them?

Comment: It is working now - see latest update in my question.I have 'site URL' set and it does work on localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the various server-side Facebook SDKs do not handle authentication in accordance with the documentation and recommended practices Facebook has shared over the last 3 or 4 months.  You found one good example of this in how the PHP SDK uses (or doesn't use) the code parameter.  There are other examples such SDKs directly reading the Facebook cookies, something Facebook engineers tell developers they should not do since the cookies are just "an implementation detail" and not something developers outside of Facebook should be building dependencies on.

I am not sure where you got that code in your working code example, but I couldn't find any support for including parameters such as `fbconnect=1`

So given that the SDK is not implementing authentication as per Facebook recommendations and documentation, and that Facebook has provided a complete PHP implementation in their documentation, I recommend you just use the version Facebook provides, copy and pasted here for your reference from this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ :

```
     <?php 

       $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
       $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
       $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

       session_start();
       $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

       if(empty($code)) {
         $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
         $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
           . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
           . $_SESSION['state'];

         echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
       }

       if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
         $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
           . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
           . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

         $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
         $params = null;
         parse_str($response, $params);

         $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
           . $params['access_token'];

         $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
         echo("Hello " . $user->name);
       }
       else {
         echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
       }

     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pat. Would you recommend avoiding the PHP-SDK entirely?

Comment: I work primarily with .NET so I don't have a lot of first hand experience with the PHP SDK.  I will tell you that I use the C# SDK just for making api calls once I have authentication handled using my own code, which is a direct adaptation of the server-side OAuth implementation recommended by Facebook -- it is pretty straightforward once you take the time to read through it.  I ignore the Facebook cookies entirely.

Comment: will auth token and other request params gets encrypted while using file_get_contents to send a request?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this.

1. Your redirect_uri should be like http://local.fb-sandbox/ . There must be a trailing slash at the end - both in the code and the facebook app settings in developers.facebook.com.
2. You have to user uurlencode on the redirect_uri.
3. Don't use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in the redirect_uri. Find a way to add any parameters you need by processing app_data or adding them depending on your user journey.

As a start replace this line:

```
'redirect_uri' => urlencode('http://local.fb-sandbox/'),
```

and experiment with adding parameters later.

Comment: code is returned by facebook on login success, why would you add it to login url?

Comment: These suggestions did not resolve the problem. I have removed potentially misleading comments. I have tried replacing that line and still get the problem. I have updated the code above. Any other ideas?

Comment: "You have to user uurlencode on the redirect_uri" << I don't think that's true.