# Access users data using AccessToken ONLY in Facebook Graph Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to Access users friends information using access token.

So i create a facebook object.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));
```

I then set the access token to that object.

```
$facebook->setAccessToken(TOKEN);
```

Then when i try to retrieve the user information it returns 0.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

So the code below does not get executed.

```
if ($user) 
{
    try 
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where my mistake lies.

Comment: You probably want to change your secret after this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Facebook PHP SDK getUser always returning 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790272/why-is-facebook-php-sdk-getuser-always-returning-0)

Comment: and thousands others..

Comment: @Shadowfax The problem is that i am using the facebook graph php sdk only and they have not set access token ...

Comment: I need to retrieve the user information and his friend list based on access token only

Comment: You have to show the authentication/login code- that's how you are getting the access toekn right?

Comment: The authentication is done on mobile device which then sends the access token to server.

Comment: You don’t need a user id being set (/automatically determined) internally for this – if you have a valid user access token, then the API will figure out itself, who `/me` is supposed to be. So just remove your `if ($user)` check around the API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl,

eg.

```
        $params = array('access_token' => self::accessToken);
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends";
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT ,'');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
   $output = json_decode($output);
```

This should give you the list of friends of the person whose access token you use.