# Facebook PHP SDK 3.2.3 getUser() return 0 when I changed server with nginX

Tags: php, facebook, apache, nginx, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to change my project server which has a facebook login function. On an old server, getUser() works fine, but it doesn't work with new server.

**OLD SERVER**

```
php 5.4.36 
apache 2.4.10 
facebook sdk 3.2.3
```

**NEW SERVER**

```
php 5.6.14
nginx 1.8.0
facebook sdk 3.2.3
```

I just changed servers and didn't change any application code.
Here is my function. This works fine on old server, but won't work on the new server.

```
function getFaceBookUserInfo(&$user){

    $config = array('appId' => FACCEBOOK_API_KEY, 
                    'secret' => FACEBOOK_API_SECRET);
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);


if ($facebook->getUser()) {  //this return 0
    try {
        $user = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
        //here logic
```

I followed the code using the SDK and eventually it broke within the function below.

**facebook.php**

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @see BaseFacebook::getPersistentData()
   */
  protected function getPersistentData($key, $default = false) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to getPersistentData.');
      return $default;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    return isset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]) ?
      $_SESSION[$session_var_name] : $default; //this return $default
  }
```

in this function, `$_SESSION[$session_var_name]` doesn't exit, so it returned $default, and eventually getUser() returns 0.

I searched and found very similar questions, but none of the answers fixed this issue.

Comment: Did you tried `print_r($_SESSION);`?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola
Yes, I did. it's like
 `Array ( [my_Id] => 0 [wp_Id] => 0 )` 
It has nothing to do with facebook SDK.
In our app, when user push login button, session start.

Comment: and I found that when I access new server, new server requests implementation of wp_cron.php in old server... now I'm more confused...is this problem related to DNS things...? –

Comment: Are you able to login in the system using facebook sdk??

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Yes, I was able to login in the system using facebook SDK **on our OLD SERVER**. so I guess application code is not wrong.  The old server and the new server has same domain. I'm doubting it's the cause of problem. now I change the host configuration in my mac `/etc/hosts` when I want to see new server.

Comment: I just want to know that what things are going wrong in a newer system. Did you identified it or not?? What values are stored in session while system is running in old server?? What values are stored in session while system is running in new server??

Comment: is it on the exact same domain?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola The value stored in session is what is made by our own system and what returns from fb in old server, but in new server, only what is made by our own system is stored in session.

Comment: @luschn
Yes, it's exact same domain.

Comment: Did you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19323397/3283363, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13278198/3283363